# PostgreSQL temporary tables

Tags: performance, postgresql, optimization, temp-tables

I need to perform a query 2.5 million times. This query generates some rows which I need to `AVG(column)` and then use this `AVG` to filter the table from all values below average. I then need to `INSERT` these filtered results into a table.

The only way to do such a thing with reasonable efficiency, seems to be by creating a `TEMPORARY TABLE` for each query-postmaster python-thread. I am just hoping these `TEMPORARY TABLE`s will not be persisted to hard drive (at all) and will remain in memory (RAM), unless they are out of working memory, of course.

I would like to know if a TEMPORARY TABLE will incur disk writes (which would interfere with the INSERTS, i.e. slow to whole process down)

Comment: And what's your question here, exactly?

Comment: Lol, sorry. I want to know if a TEMPORARY TABLE will incur disk writes (which would interfere with the INSERTS, i.e. slow to whole process down). Thx!

Comment: Ok I just read through it. It seems that the TEMPORARY TABLE does indeed induce some disk write overhead... Yet I still wonder if a copy of the whole table is kept on disk, or is it but metadata that is persisted?

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Please note that, in Postgres, the default behaviour for temporary tables is that they are not automatically dropped, and data is persisted on commit. See [`ON COMMIT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html).

Temporary table are, however, [dropped at the end of a database session](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-createtable.html#AEN67422):

> Temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session, or
>   optionally at the end of the current transaction.

There are multiple considerations you have to take into account:

- If you do want to explicitly `DROP` a temporary table at the end of a transaction, create it with the `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE ... ON COMMIT DROP` syntax.
- **In the presence of connection pooling**, a database session may span multiple client sessions; to avoid clashes in `CREATE`, you should drop your temporary tables -- either prior to returning a connection to the pool (e.g. by doing everything inside a transaction and using the `ON COMMIT DROP` creation syntax), *or* on an as-needed basis (by preceding any `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` statement with a corresponding `DROP TABLE IF EXISTS`, which has the advantage of also working outside transactions e.g. if the connection is used in auto-commit mode.)
- While the temporary table is in use, how much of it will fit in memory before overflowing on to disk?  See the [`temp_buffers`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/runtime-config-resource.html#RUNTIME-CONFIG-RESOURCE-MEMORY) option in `postgresql.conf`
- Anything else I should worry about when working often with temp tables?  A vacuum is recommended after you have DROPped temporary tables, to clean up any dead tuples from the catalog. Postgres will automatically vacuum every 3 minutes or so for you when using the default settings (`auto_vacuum`).

Also, unrelated to your question (but possibly related to your project): keep in mind that, if you have to run queries against a temp table *after* you have populated it, then it is a good idea to create appropriate indices and issue an `ANALYZE` on the temp table in question *after* you're done inserting into it.  By default, the cost based optimizer will assume that a newly created the temp table has ~1000 rows and this may result in poor performance should the temp table actually contain millions of rows.

Comment: Good stuff. Thx. I actually only used a temp table since I needed to execute two different SELECTs on it (so an Analyse would not be worth it, I fancy). I provided the operations with lots of temp_buffers, yet since TEMP tables were being created and dropped by many python threads, ...

Comment: postgres was eating up more and more RAM as the script did its job. I found that limiting the amount of python threads (running on a client computer) to a little more than the amount of cpu-cores, gave the best (most efficient and effective) execution times. Thx again for you wisdom Vlad.

Comment: Even if you only SELECT on the temp table twice, investing a few milliseconds in an index creation + ANALYZE each time you create the temp table could save you tons when/if joining other tables with the temp table - put the queries manually in PgAdminIII and use the "Query/Explain(F7)" function.

Comment: Really? Ok, I guess I needed to have someone tell me to try it since it seems counter intuitive (setup costs do not seem to be worth it). Anyway, I thank you and I will try to analyse the ANALYSE next time. I am already seeing the value of TEMP INDEXs thought. Yet I wonder if an ANALYSE is really...

Comment: worth it when the query optimizer has been configured in such a way to "strongly encourage it" to use the INDEX? Thx again Vlad.

Comment: The ANALYZE overhead is on average 100ms, and you can configure it per-table/column.  You absolutely need an ANALYZE in order for the optimizer not to make any stupid assumptions assuming that a million-row table only contains 100 rows and table-scanning it 10 times... :)

Comment: In other words, without doing ANALYZE you cannot say you have encouraged the optimizer in one way or another, as the optimizer unconditionally uses the ANALYZE data to make decisions.

Comment: what about the postgres.conf variables like sequetialscan = false?

Comment: only use enable_seqscan to debug the CBO.  trying to convince postgres to use an index by setting this is like fixing a tv with a sledgehammer - or a headache with a lobotomy.  Plus there's more than "to use an index or not to use an index" in the life of a database...

Comment: ...such as "use a nested loop with index lookup" vs. "use a hash aggregate" (and a hash aggregate might be much faster than index lookup!), questions which can only be answered by analyze statistics, not by some "don't do tablescans" configuration variable

Comment: I corrected a fundamental error in the answer. Temporary are (and were) **never persisted at the end of a session**.

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter , thanks for the update, however it needs additional warnings regarding connection pooling (i.e. what a "session" means to the back-end vs. what it means to the end-user in the presence of connection pooling.)  The original (misworded) answer was actually connection-pooling-safe; the updated one (although technically correct) may confer a false sense of security that can eventually backfire in connection-pooled environments.

Answer (score 21):

Temporary tables provide only one guarantee - they are dropped at the end of the session.  For a small table you'll probably have most of your data in the backing store.  For a large table I guarantee that data will be flushed to disk periodically as the database engine needs more working space for other requests.

EDIT:
If you're absolutely in need of RAM-only temporary tables you can create a table space for your database on a RAM disk (/dev/shm works).  This reduces the amount of disk IO, but  beware that it is currently not possible to do this without a physical disk write; the DB engine will flush the table list to stable storage when you create the temporary table.

Comment: temporary tables are also not WAL-logged http://rhaas.blogspot.com/2010/05/global-temporary-and-unlogged-tables.html