# creating postgresql temporary tables for search / reporting routine

Tags: sql, postgresql, lua, temporary

**Background Information**

We have some lua code that generates a web report.  It's taking a really long time right now and so in attempt to simplify some of the logic, I'm looking at creating a temporary table, and then joining that temp table with the results of another query.

**Sample Code:**

I tried the following as a test on the commandline:

```
psql -U username -d databasename
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TEMP1;
CREATE TABLE TEMP1 AS SELECT d_id, name as group, pname as param
FROM widgets
WHERE widget_id < 50;

SELECT count(*) from TEMP1;

\q
```

The select against the TEMP1 table show the correct results.

**Questions:**

Question 1 - How do I code this to ensure that one report request doesn't clobber another?  For example, if person A requests report A and before it's done processing, person B request report B... Will report B's creation of TEMP1 clobber the temp table created for report A? 
Is this a good reason to put everything into a transaction?

Question 2 - After running my little test described above, I quit postgresql command line.... and then logged in again.  TEMP1 was still around.  So it looks like I have to clean up the temp table when I'm done. 
I found this post: 
[PostgreSQL temporary tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486154/postgresql-temporary-tables)

which seems to indicate that temp tables are cleaned up for you when a session ends... but that doesn't seem to be working for me.  Not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE temp1 AS ...
```

This solves both questions #1 and #2 because:

1. Temporary tables live in a namespace that's private to the session, so when concurrent sessions use the same name for a temporary table, it refers to different tables, each session its own table.
2. `TEMP1` was still around after quitting because it's not temporary. You want to add the `TEMPORARY` clause (or `TEMP` for short) to the `CREATE TABLE` statement.